# What does WoW64 emulation layer do?

Tags: windows, dll, 64-bit, wow64

[image]

All WoW64 apps go through WoW64 emulation layer.
I'd like to know what happen in this layer.(especially, how they can convert address space)

Please give me some important points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have already posted the diagram it is clear that you know why WOW64 exists. Now to answer your question:

> > I'd like to know what happen in this layer.

I think you want to know how it is implemented.

Process startup: The loader loads 64-bit user-mode part 'Ntdll.dll' as usual, but also loads 32-bit Ntdll.dll in case the process is for 32-bit execution. It is now the loaders responsibility to initialize using Wow64.dll, which sets up process and thread contexts in 32-bit Ntdll and 'switches the CPU to 32-bit mode' for execution.

System Call: Everything is now running in 32-bit mode, until a system call. We know that system calls go through Ntdll.dll, User32.dll, and Gdi32.dll etc; in this case the 32-bit versions. There is a separate 32-bit version of these libraries located in \Windows\Syswow64 bit folder. These are just stubs that instead of issuing 'native system calls,' actually call in Wow64.dll. Now, it's simple for Wow64.dll to transition to 64-bit mode, convert parameters to their 64-bit counterparts, issue the system call using 64-bit versions, get the result, and reconvert the output to 32-bit. It then transitions CPU back to 32-bit mode and returns the output.

Exception dispatching, user callbacks, file system and registry operations, and I/O is handled in the same way, using hooks somewhere down the line. Read the book prescribed below.

> > (especially, how they can convert address space).

64-bit address space is a superset of 32-bit address space. Plus, the same pointer (actually PTE) in 32-bit/64-bit isn't used to refer to the whole address space, but there are separate page tables for user-space and for system space.

> > Please give me some important points.

To know windows, the most important point I can give you is to read 'Windows Internals' -- Russinovich

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249.aspx) says:

> WOW64 is the x86 emulator that allows 32-bit Windows-based applications to run seamlessly on 64-bit Windows. WOW64 is provided with the operating system and does not have to be explicitly enabled.
>
> The system isolates 32-bit applications from 64-bit applications, which includes preventing file and registry collisions. Console, GUI, and service applications are supported. The system provides interoperability across the 32/64 boundary for scenarios such as cut and paste and COM. However, 32-bit processes cannot load 64-bit DLLs for execution, and 64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit DLLs for execution.

What *specifically* do you not understand? Have you already read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) on the WoW64 subsystem? I think you'll find that it provides a fairly comprehensive overview.

And Microsoft provides some additional details here: [WOW64 Implementation Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

"especially, how they can convert address space"

the key to that is knowing that amd and intel x64 processors have support for running 32bit and 64bit code side by side.  this allows the os (when running native x64) to create a context for a 32bit thread that has 32bit addressing that coexists with the 64bit threads

in a similar way when the host os is running 32bit, it can create 16bit threads for running win16 and dos applications.

note, I don't think when running in the os 64bit that it can create 32bit AND 16bit threads - I guess amd decided that was just too much backwards compatability :-)

Comment: No, 16-bit applications are not supported under x64 versions of Windows. The MSDN link at the top of my answer explains thusly: "The primary reason is that handles have 32 significant bits on 64-bit Windows. Therefore, handles cannot be truncated and passed to 16-bit applications without loss of data."